# Change the location coordinates, change the pin and redraw the routes on a map

Tags: ios, swift3, mkmapview, mkannotation

I have created a single view application using the storyboard. I placed the mkMapView on a ViewController and embed it in navigation controller.so that the program is showing the routes between two pin that are source and destination coordinates in MKMapView .

```
   import UIKit
import MapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
    var s = 0.0
    var t = 0.0
     var sourceLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.759011, longitude: -73.984472)
    var destinationLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.748441, longitude: -73.985564)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        mapView.delegate = self

        self.dummy()
    }


    func dummy()
    {
        // 1.


        // 2.


        // 3.
        let sourcePlacemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: sourceLocation, addressDictionary: nil)
        let destinationPlacemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: destinationLocation, addressDictionary: nil)

        // 4.
        let sourceMapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: sourcePlacemark)
        let destinationMapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: destinationPlacemark)

        // 5.
        let sourceAnnotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        sourceAnnotation.title = "Times Square"

        if let location = sourcePlacemark.location {
            sourceAnnotation.coordinate = location.coordinate
        }


        let destinationAnnotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        destinationAnnotation.title = "Empire State Building"

        if let location = destinationPlacemark.location {
            destinationAnnotation.coordinate = location.coordinate
        }

        // 6.
        self.mapView.showAnnotations([sourceAnnotation,destinationAnnotation], animated: true )

        // 7.
        let directionRequest = MKDirectionsRequest()
        directionRequest.source = sourceMapItem
        directionRequest.destination = destinationMapItem
        directionRequest.transportType = .automobile

        // Calculate the direction
        let directions = MKDirections(request: directionRequest)

        // 8.
        directions.calculate {
            (response, error) -> Void in

            guard let response = response else {
                if let error = error {
                    print("Error: \(error)")
                }

                return
            }

            let route = response.routes[0]
            self.mapView.add((route.polyline), level: MKOverlayLevel.aboveRoads)

            let rect = route.polyline.boundingMapRect
            self.mapView.setRegion(MKCoordinateRegionForMapRect(rect), animated: true)
        }

    }
```

I have placed a changeLatitude button on mapView, and I am changing the map 
pin position by assigning the current source pin position to destination and source pin position latitude **s=s+0.02000** is incremented .and drop source pin at new position .

```
@IBAction func changeLatitude(_ sender: Any) {
     destinationLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: t, longitude: -73.984472)

    s=s+0.02000
    sourceLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.759011-s, longitude: -73.984472)

     t=40.759011-s;
    self.refresh()
    self.dummy()

    //self.refresh(sender: AnyObject)
```

}

I have removed the old pin from old source and old destination positions but the old route remains there i want to remove the old route .How i can remove the old route line?

```
   func refresh() {
        mapView.setCenter(mapView.userLocation.coordinate, animated: true)
        if self.mapView.overlays.count > 0
        {
            //let allAnnotations = self.mapView.annotations
            //self.mapView.removeAnnotations(allAnnotations)
           // self.mapView.removeOverlays(self.mapView.layoutGuides)
            self.mapView.removeAnnotations(self.mapView.annotations)


        }

    }
```

I and deleting old pin from KMmapView using below statement in about refresh() function

```
self.mapView.removeAnnotations(self.mapView.annotations)
```

How to remove the route line ?.

You can download the sample project from this link https://www.dropbox.com/s/77m0395nyho9die/IOS9DrawRouteMapKitTutorial1.zip?dl=0

Comment: you need move your destination always by that amount? @frincit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 self.mapView.removeOverlays(self.mapView.overlays)
```

Try This it removes overlay from your map.